How to create a Lexicon index using the root's words and their derivatives in LaTeX
(I compile with LuaLaTeX)
I am creating a Lexicon Index for a book. What I want to achieve, and have not been able to, is that this index, in addition to having specific words (e.g., Test1, Test2, Test3), also includes roots (in this case, Exis-) from which the other words sharing that root will derive.
So far, I have been using the code \indexword{}{} for the word I want to index, e.g., \indexword{Test1}{}, and in this way, the word remains in the text and also appears in the LEXICON along with its page number. However, this is where my problem begins: when I use the code \indexword{existed}{Exis-}, where the first {} is for the word I want to mark and the second {} is for the root I want to point to. When I do this, I get the issue shown in the following image:

I want to achieve what is shown in this image:

Thank you in advance.
My code:
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[width=3.93in, height=6.49in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.2in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headsep=12pt
\headheight=15pt

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ifthen} 

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=lexicon,title=LEXICON]

\newcommand{\startindices}{%
    \chapter*{LEXICON}
    \let\latexcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
    \def\cleardoublepage{%
        \def\cleardoublepage{%
            \global\let\cleardoublepage\latexcleardoublepage}}%
}


\newcommand{\indexword}[2]{%
    #1%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}
    {\index[lexicon]{#1}}
    {\index[lexicon]{#1 (#2)}}
}


\begin{document}%\sloppy


Lorem ipsum dolor \indexword{Test1}{} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut convallis urna ante, nec dapibus sem rhoncus ac. Maecenas pretium bibendum dui, sed bibendum lectus varius quis. Phasellus fringilla porta felis, commodo fermentum sem tincidunt sed. Integer eu porta ex. Quisque vel odio consectetur, suscipit leo convallis, aliquam purus. Duis in nulla arcu. Integer nunc ipsum, efficitur at dolor ac, volutpat rhoncus lacus. Aenean non risus sapien. Maecenas suscipit gravida molestie. Aenean bibendum ultrices tempor.

Sed vulputate erat libero, nec laoreet est maximus et. Pellentesque lorem libero, porttitor quis auctor quis, iaculis vel velit. Morbi vel sem lorem. Aliquam sed vulputate quam, a posuere nunc. Nullam vitae sodales \indexword{exist}{Exis-} ligula. Nullam sollicitudin augue vitae porttitor porttitor. Curabitur id ex at neque ornare eleifend. Fusce tempus, urna a laoreet imperdiet, lectus lacus laoreet leo, sit amet hendrerit risus odio ac nisi. Maecenas at egestas risus, id ullamcorper elit. Donec in ipsum vel ex dapibus condimentum eget a nibh. Phasellus felis lorem, mollis ac condimentum ac, dapibus at tortor. Fusce tincidunt aliquam posuere.

Nulla non est at libero vehicula laoreet. Proin dignissim lectus non cursus luctus. Ut ex lorem, hendrerit id laoreet ut, mollis et erat. Curabitur non vestibulum felis. In orci metus, euismod ut lorem ut, malesuada consectetur ipsum. Sed hendrerit magna turpis, in ornare urna suscipit eget. Suspendisse \indexword{Test2}{} fermentum libero interdum elit lacinia, ac lacinia ex fermentum. Ut egestas condimentum odio non lacinia.

Duis sit amet ligula eget dolor scelerisque pulvinar ac eu nisl. Praesent nisi nibh, cursus vitae volutpat at, convallis vel odio. Mauris porttitor faucibus odio in vehicula. Etiam venenatis euismod elit, sit amet suscipit risus tincidunt interdum. Aliquam pulvinar \indexword{existing}{Exis-} dui sed lectus fermentum, at congue diam scelerisque. Ut fermentum dolor vel volutpat pretium. Integer fringilla felis vitae urna blandit, vitae pharetra metus lobortis. Vivamus pulvinar iaculis nisl, quis dignissim orci tristique vel. Quisque eros nunc, aliquet a lorem sed, mattis elementum arcu.

Vivamus accumsan erat a ullamcorper fringilla. Quisque quis lobortis ligula. Aenean dictum dolor vitae elit mollis, sed commodo nisl vehicula. Mauris pharetra elementum leo. Vestibulum auctor enim a nisl auctor, a scelerisque mi tempor. Curabitur sodales nisi quis ex maximus, vitae porttitor ipsum gravida. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas bibendum magna massa, quis pharetra ante congue quis. Nullam pharetra tempor massa, sed placerat \indexword{existed}{Exis-} elit fermentum sed. Proin nec venenatis metus, eget consectetur purus. Donec ut risus odio. Cras id viverra urna. Donec ac tempor ipsum. Praesent posuere a urna vel euismod. Donec sodales, erat in hendrerit \indexword{Test3}{} ornare, justo justo congue ipsum, eget \indexword{existence}{Exis-} ornare diam sem non neque. 


\printindex[lexicon]
    
\end{document}

Let me know if you need further adjustments!

You seem to want to index the derivative words as subitems of the root.
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  width=3.93in,
  height=6.49in,
  top=1.0in,
  papersize={5.5in,8.2in},
  headsep=12pt,
  headheight=15pt,
]{geometry}
%\usepackage{xltxtra} % DON'T LOAD IT
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=lexicon,title=LEXICON]

\newcommand{\startindices}{%
  \chapter*{LEXICON}
    \let\latexcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
    \def\cleardoublepage{%
        \def\cleardoublepage{%
            \global\let\cleardoublepage\latexcleardoublepage}}%
}


\newcommand{\indexword}[2]{%
    #1%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
      {\index[lexicon]{#1}}%
      {\index[lexicon]{#2!#1}}%
}


\begin{document}


dolor \indexword{Test1}{} 

sodales \indexword{exist}{Exis-} 

Suspendisse \indexword{Test2}{}

pulvinar \indexword{existing}{Exis-} 

placerat \indexword{existed}{Exis-} 

hendrerit \indexword{Test3}{}

eget \indexword{existence}{Exis-} 

test \indexword{Test4}{}

test \indexword{Test5}{}

\printindex[lexicon]
    
\end{document}

I left just the needed packages (with one exception: xltxtra should not be loaded; it used to be sort of needed, it no longer is).
However, I suggest a different strategy: define \indexword with an optional argument (the root). This requires a syntax change, though.
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  width=3.93in,
  height=6.49in,
  top=1.0in,
  papersize={5.5in,8.2in},
  headsep=12pt,
  headheight=15pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=lexicon,title=LEXICON]

\newcommand{\startindices}{%
  \chapter*{LEXICON}
    \let\latexcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
    \def\cleardoublepage{%
        \def\cleardoublepage{%
            \global\let\cleardoublepage\latexcleardoublepage}}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\indexword}{om}{%
  #2%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\index[lexicon]{#2}}{\index[lexicon]{#1!#2}}%
}


\begin{document}


dolor \indexword{Test1}{} 

sodales \indexword[Exis-]{exist}

Suspendisse \indexword{Test2}{}

pulvinar \indexword[Exis-]{existing}

placerat \indexword[Exis-]{existed}

hendrerit \indexword{Test3}{}

eget \indexword[Exis-]{existence}

test \indexword{Test4}{}

test \indexword{Test5}{}

\printindex[lexicon]
    
\end{document}

Both codes typeset the same.


Thank you very much, it works perfectly.
